# How do I remove AWS WAF Classic from Application Load Balancer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-waf

I have an existing AWS WAF Classic associated with an Application Load Balancer.

I have created a second AWS WAFv2 to replace the existing one.

How can I remove/dissociate the existing AWS WAF Classic of the ALB so that I can add instead the newly created WAFv2?

Unlike WAFv2, in WAF Classic there does not seem to be a UI to associate or dissociate the resources protected by WAF.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question. It is found a bit hidden in the **Rules** tab.

It was unfortunate that AWS WAF docs covering both WAF and WAFv2 currently only explain how to associate and dissociate WAFv2.

Comment: You can also just associate new web ACL over it, which will disassociate the old one.